# Malware on KDE launch - how do I remove it?

Tags: malware

When I VNC to my Ubuntu server and it launches KDE, it opens two browser (Konqueror) windows (SendSpace and SpeedNetwork14 domains).

A quick Google check indicates these are malware related - how can I get rid of them?  ClamAV isn't flagging anything.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling the browser? It's probably just some rogue Javascript cookie or browser extension or something like that.

Comment: Care to show proof sendspace is malware? Looks like a mail client that allows sending large files. speednetwork14 is adware that comes from browser extentions that someone checked to install.So delete the extension or disable it.

Comment: @Rinzwind - Sendspace itself isn't specifically malware, but the file it attempts to download is. Thankfully the file has been pulled from SendSpace so it never downloads, but the popup window is still annoying.

Comment: The only extensions installed in Konqueror are Search Bar and Text-to-Speech, which I believe are defaults anyway